# Could bitcoin employ a continuously varying difficulty adjustment algorithm?

Tags: mining-theory, difficulty-retargetting

Instead of adjusting the difficulty every 2016 blocks, could the difficulty of every block be individually set based on the previous 2016 blocks? This would avoid discontinuities in difficulty, but might come with other downsides.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9305/5406, related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/65868/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/65093/5406

Comment: @Murch Definitely a duplicate of the first. Can you mark as a duplicate?

Comment: I could, but the asker can also unilaterally close as duplicate. :) You just need to click "Flag" > "Duplicate" > Paste the link.